# Redis publish/subscribe. Can an error thrown in the client receiving the message affect the server sending it?

Tags: redis, graphql, subscription

I am using graphql-apollo. The client subscribes to some messages and the server, using redis, sends them to the client.

If in the client updateQuery an error is thrown and not catched, can that, somehow, affect the running of the server function publishing the message? Could that server function crash or otherwise not finih correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It should not affect the sender's push/publish capabilities. A message published via PUB/SUB is not persisted so once you consume you have to consume no matter what happens to the consumer, it can't be put back.

This also means, if you're using Redis PUB/SUB to send/receive messages than messages can be lost due to consumer connectivity, if a consumer is down for some time than all messages sent in that window would be lost.